# Creating html table with fixed dimensions

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

## Short

Trying to get table with exact dimensions for a4 print

- Table's first and last rows' margin from **top and bottom** sides of paper must be **11 mm**
- Margin between rows' 0 mm
- Table's rows must be at **4 mm** from **left and right** sides of paper
- **2 mm** between every column
- **38 mm width x 21.2 mm height** each cell
- 13 x rows, 5 x columns, 13x5=65 cells

Here is JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/ZjBrV/

## Question

What can I do in this case? How to get the table with conditions that I explained above?

## Detailed

html table looks like that

```
<body>
  <table>
    <td> 
     <div class="bcell">
      sample text2<br/>
      <img src="..."/><br/>
      sample text2
     </div>
     </td>
   ....
  </table>
</body>
```

Using css below to achieve A4 size print result, but getting something absolutely different from conditions that I explained above.

```
        body {      
            padding:11mm 4mm 0 4mm;
            background: white;
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 210mm;
            font-size:3mm;
        }

        table { 
            page-break-after:always;
            width: 100%;
            height: 275mm;
            margin:0 auto;
            page-break-inside:avoid;                 
            border-collapse: collapse;

        }

        td img {
            height:10mm;
        }

        td {
            width: 38mm;
            height:21.2mm;
            padding: 0 1mm 0 1mm;
            font-style: bold;
            text-align: center; 
            vertical-align:middle;
        }


        tr    { 
            page-break-after:auto;
            page-break-inside:avoid; 
            height:21.2mm;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            page-break-inside:avoid;             
        }
```

Comment: This is like the third time you've asked. If you set up a jsfiddle, you'll get INSTANT results. It's much easier to tweak and play around with code than it is to try to interpret it ourselves.

Comment: @Walkerneo  http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/ZjBrV/

Comment: @Walkerneo so? have you taken a look?

Comment: I'm looking, but I'm not clear on what the problem is. What's going wrong?

Comment: @Walkerneo  I already said that, I gave exact values nearly for all parameters. But getting absolutely different results.  Take a look at this screenshot. http://screencast.com/t/AjLrtkY5kk

Comment: Are you sure you're printing in the right size? Isn't the standard 8 and half by eleven inches?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7349/discussion-between-trl13-and-walkerneo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css is not effective in changing the width of table cell elements.  What you'll want to do is either wrap the content of the cell in a div or span and use the td:first-child to set the width in the css, or use the [css table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display).

Answer (score 2):

It's clear you want the output for printing, and that the dimensions are critical; possibly you're printing onto kiss-cut label sheets or something. It seems unlikely you'll ever get an HTML solution that will produce pixel-perfect results on all browsers and operating systems. The two options I'd be considering are:

1. Generating the grid as an image and displaying it on the webpage for printing.
2. Generating the grid as a PDF for downloading and printing.

There are libraries in all server-side environments to do both of these tasks. In my experience, #2 produces the better results.